# Send an email with java in Mule CE 3.5.0

Tags: java, email, mule, esb

I'm trying to send email in Mule CE using `java` the problems that I have:

**1.**  I want take the recipient's email from this `json` file https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Rajeun/b550fe17181610f5c0f0/raw/934bf1e621d6bc056f20dee653dac74275026ba5/file.json "I don't know how to do it".
 **2.** under I post my attempts:
**Xml file:**

```
<flow name="cronsFlow2" >
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz" jobName="HTTP-Puller-Scheduler" repeatInterval="5000" repeatCount="0">
            <quartz:event-generator-job>
                <quartz:payload>HTTP Puller</quartz:payload>
            </quartz:event-generator-job>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="gist.githubusercontent.com" port="443" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="application/json" path="Rajeun/b550fe17181610f5c0f0/raw/934bf1e621d6bc056f20dee653dac74275026ba5/file.json"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[message.payload.sent]">
                <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]+ HELLO" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-variable variableName="email" value="#[message.payload.email]" doc:name="Variable"/>
                <component class="pushv.SendMail" doc:name="Java"/>
                <logger message="Error" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>

    </flow>
```

and there is my **code `java`:**

```
package pushv;


    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

    public class SendMail {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            final String username = "<Frommail>@gmail.com";
            final String password = "pass";

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
              });

            try {

                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("<Frommail>@gmail.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("<TomailfromJson>@gmail.com"));
                message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

                Transport.send(message);

                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR 2015-03-29 17:40:36,648 [[pushv].cronsFlow2.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver: The required property "method" is not set on the event
ReflectionEntryPointResolver: Could not find entry point on: "pushv.SendMail" with arguments: "{class java.util.LinkedHashMap}"
AnnotatedEntryPointResolver: Component: pushv.SendMail@13508f6 doesn't have any annotated methods, skipping.
CallableEntryPointResolver: Object "pushv.SendMail@13508f6" does not implement required interface "interface org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable"
]
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-321
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver: The required property "method" is not set on the event
ReflectionEntryPointResolver: Could not find entry point on: "pushv.SendMail" with arguments: "{class java.util.LinkedHashMap}"
AnnotatedEntryPointResolver: Component: pushv.SendMail@13508f6 doesn't have any annotated methods, skipping.
CallableEntryPointResolver: Object "pushv.SendMail@13508f6" does not implement required interface "interface org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable"
] (org.mule.model.resolvers.EntryPointNotFoundException)
  org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet:49 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/model/resolvers/EntryPointNotFoundException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.model.resolvers.EntryPointNotFoundException: Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver: The required property "method" is not set on the event
ReflectionEntryPointResolver: Could not find entry point on: "pushv.SendMail" with arguments: "{class java.util.LinkedHashMap}"
AnnotatedEntryPointResolver: Component: pushv.SendMail@13508f6 doesn't have any annotated methods, skipping.
CallableEntryPointResolver: Object "pushv.SendMail@13508f6" does not implement required interface "interface org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable"
]
    at org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.invoke(DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.java:49)
    at org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:339)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:82)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Any help please. and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using a Java class and using `public static void main(String[] args)` in your class and that's the reason it is failing and is unable to find the method to call

Instead of using a Java file and making it complex, you can simply use a smtp out bound as follow with a set-payload :-

```
<set-payload value="Dear Mail Crawler,
                    \n\n No spam to my email, please!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" 
    user="myemail%40gmail.com" password="pass" to= "#[message.payload.email]"
    from="Rajeun" subject="Testing Subject" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="Gmail" doc:name="Send notification email"/>
```

PS:- If you want to use a java class to send your email, then remove `public static void main(String[] args)` from your java class and use entrypoint resolver to invoke your method (If your java class contain multiple methods) 
refer :- http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-school-invoking-component-methods-using-entry-point-resolvers/

**UPDATED ANSWER**

put the following at top:-

```
<smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Then use the following in your flow using `connector-ref="Gmail"` with the smtp outbound as follow:-

```
  <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com"  port="587" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" connector-ref="Gmail" from="Rajeun" password="pass" subject="Mule Test with Velocity Transformer"
          to="#[flowVars['email']]" user="myemail%40gmail.com"  />
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I thought the SMTP connector is not supported in CE because whe i try it i get an other error. please take a look on this link http://pastebin.com/xSbtJqE8  you can find my new code and the error i get thank you.